# How to pump data from Prometheus to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, apache-kafka-connect

Can we configure Prometheus to **push** data to Kafka?

If not, is there a Prometheus **source** connector available that could be run on Kafka Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Prometheus Integration documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/), it links to a project for writing to Kafka as a [remote store](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write).

Comment: remote_write looks promising, thanks. As for Exporters, do you mean there is one that can push data to Kafka?

Comment: I have no experience with these. You'd have to refer to the individual projects to see their capabilities and limitations. If it's anything like the JMX exporter, then it's actually another scape target to get data into Prometheus, not get data out

Comment: From what I can see all Prometheus exporters are about exporting data from various data sources and importing it into Prometheus, which is the opposite of what I described in my question. The first part of your answer seems to hit the nail on the head though. Please, edit or remove the exporters part and I'll accept it.

Comment: Agreed. Edited answer